# How to display our output meseeges into specified uipanel in Matlab GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I want to display my output messages that have processes in a function. The message is stored in a variable.

In the GUI window, I made an uipanel with tag=uipanel1.

So, my question is how do I display my messages in the specified uipanel that I made (uipanel1)?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but it is hard to guess the most appropriate way without some information on what you already tried. I would suggest the following options:

1. If your `uipanel` is not high and is used much like statusbar in gui applications then you better add a `static text` component to it and update its text through its handle.
2. While static test can also display multiline text it will not display scrollbars. If you want to display something like a message log window with several lines visible and scroll bars, I'd suggest to add a `listbox` instead. However, it will be a little tricky if you want to show only limited number of most resent messages.